# Extjs4, How to get textfield value

Tags: extjs4

I have a problem with getting textField value.

View :

I have Toobar variable and I add to tbar of my panel.

```
var orderListTbar = Ext.create('Ext.Toolbar',{
    id : 'orderListTbar',
    items : [
        '',{
            xtype : 'radiofield',
            name : 'searchType',
            value : 'order_name',
            boxLabel : 'Order Name'
        },'',{
            xtype : 'radiofield',
            name : 'searchType',
            value : 'order_no',
            boxLabel : 'Order No'
        },'',{
            xtype : 'radiofield',
            name : 'searchType',
            value : 'status',
            boxLabel : 'Status'
        },'=',{
            xtype : 'textfield',
            name : 'keyword',
            value : 'Keyword'
        },'|',{
            xtype : 'datefield',
            name : 'order_from',
            fieldLabel : 'From ',
            labelWidth : 40,
            width : 150,
            value : new Date() 
        },'~',{
            xtype : 'datefield',
            name : 'order_to',
            fieldLabel : "To ",
            labelWidth : 40,
            width : 150,
            value : new Date()
        },'|',{
            xtype : 'button',
            name : 'searchBtn',
            text : "Search"
        }
    ]
});
```

And In my controller. I want to get the fields value.

```
init : function(application){        

        this.control({
            "#orderListTbar button[name=searchBtn]" : {
                click : function(){
                    orderFrom = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#orderListTbar [name=order_from]');
                    console.log(orderFrom); // it return Object as well
                    console.log(orderFrom.value); // BUT, it return undefined!!!! @.@

                }
            }
        });
    },
```

anybody know what I did wrong?

and If you have found something wrong in my codes, please advice me.

Thank you!

Comment: and I am not sure to use "Ext.ComponentQuery.query()" to trace fields. If I am wrong, please advice me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `getValue` method instead of `value` property. `value` is not listed in API.
Also notice that `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` returns array.

Comment: I also tried getValue() too, but the error message say "orderFrom.getValue is not a function" @.@

Comment: I noticed that `query` returns array. Try `orderFrom[0].getValue()`

Comment: May I ask one more question? I successfully get the datefield value and I print into console.log but it show "Date {Tue Mar 13 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}" like that, I expected '3/13/2012'. and the textbox show '3/13/2012'. do you now how I get the date value with m-d-Y format? thanks!

Comment: `Ext.form.field.Date.getValue` returns `Date` object which has `format` method. [Here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) are examples

Comment: Indeed. I must had always had some extension in `Date` prototype. I don't see anything useful in w3c api. I guess you have to play with getXXX methods from date. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) link for API.

Answer (score 3):

Another type of script is allowed as follows:

```
orderFrom = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("[name=order_from]",orderListTbar);
```